# Expand/Collapse dynamic GridViewRow in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am dynamically creating a `GridViewRow` in `RowCreated` event of gridview and I need to expand/collapse this particular row alone on button click.

```
GridViewRow HeaderGridRow1 = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
TableCell HeaderCell1 = new TableCell();
TableCell HeaderCellEC = new TableCell();

ImageButton imgEC = new ImageButton();
imgEC.ImageUrl = "Images.png";
imgEC.ID = "imgShowHide";
imgEC.Click += ImgShowHide_Click;
HeaderCellEC.Controls.Add(imgEC);
HeaderGridRow1.Cells.Add(HeaderCellEC);

HeaderCell1.Text = "Info";
HeaderGridRow1.Cells.Add(HeaderCell1);
GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(1, HeaderGridRow1);
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void ImgShowHide_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Now in `ImgShowHide_Click` event I need to perform expand/collapse on `HeaderGridRow1`. Since its dynamic control how can I achieve it.